# Sorting and manipulating a hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my rails 3.1 project I have a Book model that has a ID, NAME, and BOOK_ORDER. I am using the [ranked-model](https://github.com/harvesthq/ranked-model) gem, which for its sorting process creates large numbers in the sorting(:book_order) column. Im looking for some help to create a method to sort all of the Books by the :book_order column, then simplify the :book_order numbers.

So, I have this:

controller

```
@books = Books.all
```

view

```
<% @books.each do |book| %>
 <%= book.book_order %>
<% end %> 

# book1.book_order => 1231654
# book2.book_order => 9255654
# book3.book_order => 1654
```

But want this:

view

```
<% @books.each do |book| %>
 <%= book.clean_book_order %>
<% end %> 

# book1.clean_book_order => 2
# book2.clean_book_order => 3
# book3.clean_book_order => 1
```

Additionally, i don’t want to change the database entry, just use its current values to make simpler ones.

Thanks!

---

UPDATE:

Thanks to nash’s response I was able to find a solution:

In my Book Model I added the clean_book_order method:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base     
  include RankedModel
  ranks :book_order 

  def clean_book_order
    self.class.where("book_order < ?", book_order).count + 1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% @books.each do |book| %>
 <%= book.book_order_position %>
<% end %>
```

EDIT:

Oh, I see. https://github.com/harvesthq/ranked-model/issues/10

Comment: I have already tried that, but it doesn’t work.  I think that only works for adding/ updating attributes.  Thanks though